# Making sure AngularJS two-way binding is updated

Tags: angularjs

I have a form for submitting a comment with two-way binding to an AngularJS 1.4 controller. When a comment is sent, I would like to clear the comment-textarea and resize it to one row using `autosize()` from the library http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/ .. Autosize is used for resizing the `textarea` if a user types a long comment.

However, it seems the `autosize` happens before the comment input is cleared out. So this means the textarea will remain the size of the entered text.

This code works, but I find it ugly to just wait 50ms. What should I do to ensure the `textarea` two-way binding has been updated before calling `$scope.updateTextareaSize();`?

My code is

```
commentService.storeComment($scope.text)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.text = '';    // The comment which is two-way bound.

        setTimeout(function() { $scope.$evalAsync( 
            $scope.updateTextareaSize() );     // Call autosize()
        }, 50);        // Update textarea size after the angular bindings have updated. Assuming this is done in 50ms.
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instead use the [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service with a timeout of 0.

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.updateTextareaSize() // Call autosize()
}, 0);
```

When you do this it makes your `$scope.updateTextareaSize()` function run after all of Angular's internal plumbing in the `$digest` such as updating the two way binding.

Comment: or you can just do this instead, it's the same thing.
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.updateTextareaSize() // Call autosize()
});