# Display tour for first time user

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a guided tour for the first time user of my site. It works perfectly on localhost, but when I upload it onto my dev server it doesn't work properly i.e. the tooltips are not at the designated place. See the following two screenshots - 
[image: Localhost Pic]

[image: Development server]

I think the issue is because the component is not loaded so far i think so the rendering of the tooltip happens in the middle of the page.

Repository I am using is [here](https://github.com/mendhak/angular-intro.js)

Code - **Controller**

```
$scope.IntroOptions = {
        steps:[
        {
            element: '#step1',
            intro: "<b>First Step First: </b>Click here to define structure of your test scripts!!<br/>You can modify this later on any time",
            position: 'left'
        },
        {
            element: '#step2',
            intro: "Click here to select a folder/test script spreadsheet from google drive.",
            position: 'bottom'
        }] 
,
        showStepNumbers: false,
        exitOnOverlayClick: false,
        exitOnEsc: false,
        nextLabel: '<strong>NEXT!</strong>',
        prevLabel: '<span style="color:green">Previous</span>',
        skipLabel: 'Exit',
        doneLabel: 'Thanks!'
    };
    $scope.ShouldAutoStart = false;

    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.CallMe();
    }, 0);
```

HTML code -

```
<div ng-controller="tourController" class="container-narrow">
    <div ng-intro-options="IntroOptions" ng-intro-method="CallMe"
             ng-intro-oncomplete="CompletedEvent" ng-intro-onexit="ExitEvent"
             ng-intro-onchange="ChangeEvent" ng-intro-onbeforechange="BeforeChangeEvent"
             ng-intro-onafterchange="AfterChangeEvent"
             ng-intro-autostart="ShouldAutoStart">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**I tried using angular.element(document).ready() also but its not working.

> Things are working now with timeout 1000 mili secs but i think there
>   must be a better way of doing this

Comment: Works perfectly for me on chrome. Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Yes, I tried clearing cache, it works sometime, sometimes doesn't.....timeout 1000 makes it working i think

Comment: but I think that should not be correct way to do that, is there any better way?

Comment: Normally you can use in $timeout of 0 in these cases. I made this answer a while back that'll show you what I mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075839/making-sure-angularjs-two-way-binding-is-updated/32075891#32075891. It not work here though which is why I'm commenting and not answering haha.

Comment: haha...ok btw timeout 1000 milisecs worked but i still think there must be a better way

Comment: the site works fine for me.. in fact i would like to know if you used third-party angular component for that guide

Comment: This is likely an issue of load time, your script seems to start while not all ressources have been loaded. Did you try `$(document).ready(...` or  `body.onload(...`?

Comment: Axel I did tried that as well...with angular.element(document).ready() but didn't work

Comment: @nosthertus yes the site is working fine after putting a timeout of 1 sec for the start of the guide...but I thought if there is some better way to do that? Yes, Third party angular component used...link in the question